# Why xtratabpage width is 0?

Tags: c#, devexpress, tabcontrol

I'm using `xtratabcontrol` from `devexpress`,,

I need to get the width of the header .

So I write (getting first header width)

```
int width = browserTabControl.TabPages[0].TabPageWidth;
```

it gets zero !! although here's the tabpage :

[image: TabPageWidth is 0]

why is this occuring ?

any other ideas to 
get the header width are welcomed

thanx in advance

Comment: probabbly because there is no any control inside, or (it depends on UI library which I'm not familiar with), you call this code *before* layout of control is constructed and/or calculated.

Comment: I'm not understanding you , but where to add the code ?

Comment: Tigran said that there are no any child control on the specified tab. On the picture there you show only tab header but not tab itself. So probably he is right. Where to add this code - it depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @VasilySemenov , ever when I add controls , the same problem

Comment: @KaramNajjar: that means, repeat *probabbly* that the line of code you call is somehow *before* actually contorl is fully creared. Try to add a button (for only debug reason to tab) and on click of it add your code for width control.

Comment: @Tigran , I'm doing this in close button click event , when closing another tab I need to get the width of the first one , so I call the width after the tab is fully loaded !

Comment: @KaramNajjar: is this a WPF ?

Comment: @Tigran : no , winform

Answer (score 0):

try instaed of

```
int width = browserTabControl.TabPages[0].TabPageWidth;
```

this code :

```
int width = browserTabControl.TabPages[0].Width;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the [XtraTabPage.TabPageWidth](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTabXtraTabPage_TabPageWidthtopic) property is set to 0, the header width of the current page is determined by the [XtraTabControl.TabPageWidth](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTabXtraTabControl_TabPageWidthtopic) property. And if the XtraTabControl.TabPageWidth property is set to 0, the headers will be **auto-sized to fit the header text**.